# ASP MVC 4 Authentification Get User Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So, i am implementing authentification in my app.
Creditianals stored in xml files(not real project).

Here is code:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Objects", new ObjectsModel(//user name));
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }


public class CustomMembershipProvider : SimpleMembershipProvider
{
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class ObjectsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ObjectsModel(//get authentificated username));
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Am i doing it right? Or i must use WebSecurity etc. And is it enough for secure app? Or i have great misunderstanding of whole staff?
2. How i can get loged in UserName in ObjectsController(commented line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Am i doing it right? Or i must use WebSecurity etc. And is it enough for secure app? Or i have great misunderstanding of whole staff?***

- Custom authentication requires lot of work to do as part of Membership infrastructure which contains *UserContext*, *UserProfiles*, *IPrincipal*. If you just want to validate user against file instead model/dbcontext, that can be done with minimal efforts with standard **WebSecurity** implementation.
- Visual Studio comes with asp.net mvc template project membership implementation-ready code. It will give you deep glimpse of models, context.

You can see [this article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) for more information.

***How i can get loged in UserName in ObjectsController(commented line)?***

- Ideally your custom authentication should expose IPrincipal user context(User.Identity), which you can utilize everywhere around the project views/controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with `Asp.Net MVC Template project membership` implementation-ready code.(Yes @PalakBhansali answer is correct).

You can get sample application by Creating New project in visual studio. You can able to modify the codes as your wish.

`File-> New -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET MVC 4/3/2 Application`.

**Note :** Not an Empty Web Application

- It will be a Secure app.
- You can get logged in User Name through `@User.Identity.Name`.
- Then You are doing right for learning project.

Good Luck ;)